# Application not opening on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, From last two days I'm trying to opening my applications but I'm not getting any response,few thing opening like chrome,firefox, terminal, ubuntu software, text editor(built-in). But When I'm trying to open my other application like VLC, sublime-text, Pycharm, Atom they are not opening. I tried few thing like restarting my PC, trying to install new package from Ubuntu software but they are still not opening. Can anyone suggest me any solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: What happens if you run `vlc` in terminal?